# Using Javascript/JQuery Mouseover fades in Firefox (keeps repeating)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use JS/JQuery to make tiles that will fade out then fade in with different data (In this case it is pictures) when you over on it and then reverse it when you mouse off of it. Now my code works fine in Chrome but when I test it in FireFox it keeps executing the fade in/out commands. I looked up similar situations where people use the `$(this).stop().fadeOut(function()` code but since I am doing multiple fades and loading information it won't do the animation correctly. Does anyone know a solution to this?

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var hov = false;
    $(".previewBox").mouseenter(function()
    {
        if(hov === false)
        {
            hov = true;
            $(this).fadeOut(function() 
            { 
                $(this).load(function() 
                { 
                    $(this).fadeIn(); 
                }); 
                $(this).attr("src", "Images/Portfolio/Art_Bike_Flip.png"); 
            });
        };
    });

    $(".previewBox").mouseleave(function()
    {
        if(hov === true)
        {
            hov = false;
            $(this).fadeOut(function()
            {
                $(this).load(function()
                {   
                    $(this).fadeIn();
                });
            $(this).attr("src", "Images/Portfolio/Art_Bike_Preview.png");
            }); 
        };
    });
});
</script>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here. First `.load` is not a reliable way to detect image loading. Some browsers, when the image is cached, wont fire a load event, so the script will fail. You need to use a plugin like `waitForImages` or `imageLoaded`.

https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages I recommend this one.

Also `.stop()` will work fine for your needs, if it seems to cancel fades in some instances, try `.stop(true, true)`, it should animate just fine, even with loading data and multiple fades. You may need to tune it so that the stop command only is placed on the last fade to occur.

also you are making a ton of jQuery objects when you only need one. Limiting it to one object will make your script substantially more efficient.

```
var previewBox = $('.previewBox');
```

Then you can use that one everywhere:

```
previewBox.mouseenter(function()
{
   if(hov === false)
   {
      hov = true;
      previewBox.stop().fadeOut(function(){
           previewBox.imagesLoaded(function...
```

In your case with the multiple instances using a class, you need to isolate your events from one another. You can do this with `.each`

```
$('.previewBox').each(function(){
     var previewBox = $(this);
     previewBox.mouseenter(function(){ ....
```

By wrapping all your current logic in a `.each` you will avoid interaction of events between elements. In this way the events `mouseenter mouseleave` and the attached logic will bind isolated to each instance of an element with that class, instead of binding to all elements of that class.

Comment: Thanks @Fresheyeball for the quick answer! The problem that I am getting with the variable is now it seems that it acts for every element on the screen that is using the previewBox CSS class. I got multiple images(Tiles) that use it to give them dropShadow and some other things. Also even when I put the .stop() on the last fade `previewBox.stop().fadeIn();` it only fades out. I have the website running live off of one of my school servers so maybe it is doing something that I am missing. [link](http://people.rit.edu/~mpn3712/309/Portfolio/) Let me know if you find anything!

Comment: There you go. You just need to separate your selection with a `.each`, then `.stop()` will work perfect for you :)